# How to ignore multiple occurrence of search keywords in Mongodb $text search?

Tags: database, mongodb, search, indexing, full-text-search

I have a simple blog post website where different authors can create articles, which consists of `title` and `content` field. I used **mongodb** due to legacy implementation and other factors.

In the website, it has a search bar where user can do a free text search to get a list of relevant articles. And in the backend, I used Mongodb [text index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/indexes/index-types/index-text) and [$text search](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) to do the queries.

How I created the index (title has more weight)

```js
db.articles.createIndex(
  { title: "text", content: "text" },
  {
    weights: {
      title: 10,
      content: 1
    },
    name: "ArticleIndex"
  }
)
```

Example query

```js
db.articles.find(
  { $text: { $search: "coffee bake" } },
  { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
).sort(
  { score: { $meta: "textScore", _id: -1 } }
)
```

In the query, I put an additional `_id: -1` so that latest created articles will be put first if there's a tie.

Now the problem is, some of the authors tried to manipulate the sorting by putting certain keywords multiple times in the `content`, to the extent that it looks quite obvious. For instance, most of my users would search a city name `New York`. Hence, a particular author spams the phrase `New York` all over the `content`. Due to this, his article gets a high text score based on Mongodb $text search, and always appears at the top.

Is there a way in Mongodb $text search to ignore multiple occurrence of the search keywords? Also, is there a way to somehow include the `_id` field to contribute to the sorting score, i.e. latest item will have higher scores?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort directly with `$meta`. So you can `$addFields` to add score and sort by score and id. Example:

```
[{
 $match: {
  $text: {
   $search: 'coffee bake'
  }
 }
}, {
 $addFields: {
  scoreSearch: {
   $meta: 'textScore'
  }
 }
}, {
 $sort: {
  scoreSearch: -1,
  id: -1
 }
}]
```

Comment: But what I did is exactly what's in the official documentation. Also, unfortunately this doesn't really address my issue which is how a document can easily get a high score just by spamming the search keywords in the content.

Comment: @hskris spamming keywords is a trick to help the post on top, that have another system. If you want remove this trick, you remove sort by `scoreSearch`. I suggest you to use `$or` for search by priority and use match like text same search like in sql. Example, with `coffee bake` have in field `title` is higher than `context` => `
{
  $or: [
    { name:  /coffee bake/ },
    { context: /coffee bake/}
  ]
}`